# Suppose $f=(x-a)^r h$ prove that $f'=(x-a)^{r-1} h_1$ where $ h_1 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ where does not vanish at $a$.

Tags: polynomials

---

Suppose $$f=(x-a)^r h  \in C[x] \text{ where } h(a)\neq 0$$  prove that $$f'=(x-a)^{r-1} h_1 \text{ where } h_1 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$$  where  does not vanish at $a$.

**Hint:** use product rule

---

the derivative of $$f=c_0 x^n =c_1 x^{n-1} +\dots + c_{n-1}x +c_n \in C[x]$$

the *formal derivative* is defined by the usual formulas from calculus:

$$ f'=nc_0 x^{n-1} +(n-1 ) c_1 x^{n-2} + \dots + c_{n-1}+0$$
the following rules of differentiation apply

$$ \begin{aligned}
   (a f) '&=af'&&  a\in C 
\\ (f+g)'&=f'+g'
\\ (fg)'&=f'g+fg'
\end{aligned}$$

---

not to sure if $h$ is just a constant I will first assume that it is then try to show when its not.

leting $f=g h $ where $g(x)=(x-a)^r_1$  and $h=h$. Taking the derivatives $g'(x)=(x-a)^{r_1-1} $ and $h'=h'$

**assuming $h$** is a constant $h'=0$
so 
$$\begin{aligned}
f'=g'h+g*h'=(x-a)^{r-1}*h+(x-a)^r_1*0=(x-a)^{r-1}*h
\end{aligned} $$

h does not vanish at a.

**Assuming h ** is not a constant
$$\begin{aligned}
f'&=g'h+g*h'=(x-a)^{r-1}*h+(x-a)^r_1*h'
\\ &\vdots ( Not sure)
\\f'&=(x-a)^{r-1}*h_1
\end{aligned} $$

where $h_1$ does not vanish at a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have it done. Following your calculations, if you call $h_1(x)=h(x)+(x-a)\cdot h'(x)$, then $h_1(a)=h(a)$, so it does not vanish at $a$.